# any JSON string convert into C# Object without defining pojo

Tags: c#, json

I have to de-serialize any given JSON String to C# Object. The JSON String is dynamic. So i cannot define Class structure for that Object. I want some dynamic approach where C# should handle internally.

I have already tried using

```
dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Json);
```

Above gives me some meta data counts and complex structure which was not helpful. I just need only object. 
Also i have used

```
object result = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(Json);
```

above does not handle the Array type. 
sample JSON's

```
json1:[{"associatedToId":null,"associationType":null,"isObsolete":null}]

json2:{"commercialName":"[\"\",\"\"]","commercialActivity":"[\"\",\"\"]"}

json3:["شر*************************","Gu******************************"]
```

I need code to deserialize it to an object. which i will be using further for recursion and correcting data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by deserialising to a dictionary object, which itself is a set or name/value pairs.

For an example, see here:

- [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)